# The result of subscribe is not used

Tags: android, android-studio, rx-java2, lint, android-studio-3.1

I've upgraded to Android Studio 3.1 today, which seems to have added a few more lint checks. One of these lint checks is for one-shot RxJava2 `subscribe()` calls that are not stored in a variable. For example, getting a list of all players from my Room database:

```
Single.just(db)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(db -> db.playerDao().getAll());
```

Results in a big yellow block and this tooltip:

> The result of `subscribe` is not used

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio. Code is highlighted in Yellow with a tooltip. Tooltip text: The result of subscribe is not used.]

What is the best practice for one-shot Rx calls like this? Should I keep hold of the `Disposable` and `dispose()` on complete? Or should I just `@SuppressLint` and move on?

This only seems to affect RxJava2 (`io.reactivex`), RxJava (`rx`) does not have this lint.

Comment: Of both your solutions, I honestly think @SuppressLint is not the best one. Maybe I'm wrong but I really think code should never alter the IDE warnings and/or hints

Comment: @ArthurAttout Agreed, currently I'm keeping hold of the `Disposable` at member scope and calling `dispose()` when the single completes, but it seems needlessly cumbersome. I'm interested to see if there's any better ways of doing this.

Comment: I think this lint warning is annoying when the RxJava stream isn't subscribed-to from within an Activity/Fragment/ViewModel. I have a Completable that can safely run without any regard for the Activity lifecycle, yet I still need to dispose of it?

Comment: consider RxLifecycle

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The IDE does not know what potential effects your subscription can have when it's not disposed, so it treats it as potentially unsafe. For example, your `Single` may contain a network call, which could cause a memory leak if your `Activity` is abandoned during its execution.

A convenient way to manage a large amount of `Disposable`s is to use a [CompositeDisposable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/disposables/CompositeDisposable.html); just create a new `CompositeDisposable` instance variable in your enclosing class, then add all your Disposables to the CompositeDisposable (with RxKotlin you can just append `addTo(compositeDisposable)` to all of your Disposables). Finally, when you're done with your instance, call `compositeDisposable.dispose()`.

This will get rid of the lint warnings, and ensure your `Disposables` are managed properly.

In this case, the code would look like:

```
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

Disposable disposable = Single.just(db)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(db -> db.get(1)));

compositeDisposable.add(disposable); //IDE is satisfied that the Disposable is being managed. 
disposable.addTo(compositeDisposable); //Alternatively, use this RxKotlin extension function.


compositeDisposable.dispose(); //Placed wherever we'd like to dispose our Disposables (i.e. in onDestroy()).
```

Comment: I'm getting compile error `error: cannot find symbol method addTo(CompositeDisposable)` with "rxjava:2.1.13". Where does this method come from? (RxSwift or RxKotlin I suppose)

Comment: Yes, it's an RxKotlin method.

Comment: what to do in case of flowable

Comment: What if we are doing this in doOnSubscribe

Comment: It would not cause a memory leak. Once the network call finishes and the onComplete is called, the garbage collection will deal with the rest unless you've kept an explicit reference of the disposable and don't dispose it.

Comment: It's not work for me. I used Observable in Retrofit

Comment: @GabrielVasconcelos what if the network call never finishes? Or passes context somewhere else? We need to notify upstream producers that the observing is done and to release any resources we passed to them.

Answer (score 27):

The moment the Activity will be destroyed, the list of Disposables gets cleared and we’re good.

```
io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable mDisposable;

    mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    mDisposable.add(
            Single.just(db)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(db -> db.get(1)));

    mDisposable.dispose(); // dispose wherever is required
```

Answer (score 16):

You can subscribe with [DisposableSingleObserver](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/DisposableSingleObserver.html):

```
Single.just(db)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object obj) {
                // work with the resulting todos...
                dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // handle the error case...
                dispose();
            }});
```

In case you need to directly dispose `Single` object (e.g. before it emits) you can implement method `onSubscribe(Disposable d)` to get and use the `Disposable` reference.

You can also realize `SingleObserver` interface by your own or use other child classes.

Answer (score 5):

As was suggested you may use some global `CompositeDisposable` to add the result of the subscribe operation there.

The [RxJava2Extensions](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions) library contains useful methods to automatically remove created disposable from the `CompositeDisposable` when it completes. See [subscribeAutoDispose](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#subscribeautodispose) section.

In your case it may look like this

```
SingleConsumers.subscribeAutoDispose(
    Single.just(db)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
    composite,
    db -> db.playerDao().getAll())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Uber [AutoDispose](https://github.com/uber/AutoDispose) and rxjava [`.as`](https://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#as-io.reactivex.ObservableConverter-)

```
        Single.just(db)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .as(AutoDispose.autoDisposable(AndroidLifecycleScopeProvider.from(this)))
            .subscribe(db -> db.playerDao().getAll());
```

Make sure that you understand when you unsubscribe based on the ScopeProvider.

Comment: This assumes a lifecycle provider is available. Also, the "as" method is marked as unstable, so using it will result in a Lint warning.

Comment: Thanks @Dabbler, agreed. The [.as](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Observable.java#L5096) method was experimental until RxJava 2.1.7 and on 2.2 it's stable.

Answer (score 2):

Again and again I find myself coming back to the question of how to correctly dispose of subscriptions, and to this posting in particular. Several blogs and talks claim that failing to call `dispose` necessarily leads to a memory leak, which I think is a too general statement. In my understanding, the lint warning about not storing the result of `subscribe` is a non-issue in some cases, because:

- Not all observables run in the context of an Android activity
- The observable can be synchronous
- Dispose is called implicitly, provided the observable completes

Since I don't want to suppress lint warnings I recently started to use the following pattern for cases with a synchronous observable:

```
var disposable: Disposable? = null

disposable = Observable
   .just(/* Whatever */)
   .anyOperator()
   .anyOtherOperator()
   .subscribe(
      { /* onSuccess */ },
      { /* onError */ },
      {
         // onComplete
         // Make lint happy. It's already disposed because the stream completed.
         disposable?.dispose()
      }
   )
```

I'd be interested in any comments on this, regardless of whether it's a confirmation of correctness or the discovery of a loophole.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way available, which is avoiding to use Disposables manually (add and remove subscriptions).

You can define an **Observable** and that observable is going to receive the content from a *SubjectBehaviour* (in case you use RxJava). And by passing that observable to your *LiveData*, that should work. Check out the next example based on the initial question:

```
private val playerSubject: Subject<Player> = BehaviorSubject.create()

private fun getPlayer(idPlayer: String) {
        playerSubject.onNext(idPlayer)
}

private val playerSuccessful: Observable<DataResult<Player>> = playerSubject
                        .flatMap { playerId ->
                            playerRepository.getPlayer(playerId).toObservable()
                        }
                        .share()

val playerFound: LiveData<Player>
    get() = playerSuccessful
        .filterAndMapDataSuccess()
        .toLiveData()

val playerNotFound: LiveData<Unit>
    get() = playerSuccessful.filterAndMapDataFailure()
        .map { Unit }
        .toLiveData()

// These are a couple of helpful extensions

fun <T> Observable<DataResult<T>>.filterAndMapDataSuccess(): Observable<T> =
filter { it is DataResult.Success }.map { (it as DataResult.Success).data }

fun <T> Observable<DataResult<T>>.filterAndMapDataFailure(): Observable<DataResult.Failure<T>> =
filter { it is DataResult.Failure }.map { it as DataResult.Failure<T> }
```