# RxJava 2, RoomDb and Disposing

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm trying to create a DatabaseHelper class to separate out some Room things. DatabaseHelper is not an Activity or Fragment. I'm trying to do something like the following

```
 roomDb.mediaItemDownloadDao()
            .findById(mediaItemId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(oldDownload -> {
                oldDownload.setSomeField(true);
                roomDb.mediaItemDownloadDao().insert(oldDownload);
            });
}
```

but it tells me the result of subscribe is not used. is there a way to make sure that is executed and then dispose immediately ?  should i be passing the disposable up to the caller? whats the best way to accomplish what i want / use rx objects outside of a fragment / activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i think instead of going to RX for this i want to use

```
 rx.schedulers.Schedulers.io().createWorker()
```

and just put the work in there =]

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522619/the-result-of-subscribe-is-not-used) is similar to yours. I would add that you should add your subscription `Disposable` to a `CompositeDisposable` in your helper, and when the parent Activity is destroyed, chain down a call to dispose your `CompositeDisposable`.

Comment: I was more so looking at how to do this in the case of a download service, so i think removing the need for a composite/activity/etc and going with schedulers is the path i want.